# Python 3.1 image library

Tags: python, image, image-processing

So, is there an image processing library for Python 3.x? There is Python Imaging Library ([PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)) but the last supported Python version is 2.7 (*"A version for 3.X will be released later."*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyQt provides image processing functionality and is available for Python 3, if you can live with a dependency of that size and with such license restrictions.