# Python module for the image processing

Tags: python, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image Processing, In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94875/image-processing-in-python)

There is a Python module for image processing?

I would like to analyze, modify and create other images.

Comment: One can also search on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94875/image-processing-in-python , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641187/php-or-python-for-image-processing , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721329/python-3-1-image-library , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188552/are-there-image-processing-modules-for-python-3

Answer (score 6):

check the Image Module
http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

next time, try to google it :) unless you have some special requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try the Python Image Library:

http://www.pythonware.com/library/

Some of it is a bit abstract (like the methods for manipulating image statistics) but in general it supports most formats.

**Update** There is a fork http://python-pillow.org/ which looks fairly active.

Comment: looks like it's a dead project. last release was on 2009